# TFS Custom Build Tasks - Multiple versions

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to make changes to a custom TFS build task. I'd like to bundle the new version of the task in my extension (leaving the current version in as well) and be able to select the version when editing a build/release definition.

I've looked over Microsoft's documentation for [bundling multiple versions of a build task within one extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/build-task-schema#bundle-multiple-versions-of-build-tasks-within-one-extension), but I'm not seeing the details of what needs to be included in the extension manifest.

I've also looked at the [VSTS Tasks on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks) and I'm not seeing how to accomplish this.

Does anyone have an example of how to bundle multiple versions of a task in one extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for Visual Studio Team Services, you may have to wait until TFS 2017u2 is out to be able to do this against TFS.

- Create a parent folder for both tasks (`Task`)
- Put each build task in its own folder (`Task\TaskV1`, `Task\TaskV2`).
- Make sure they're different by major version in the task.json
- Make sure they have the same TaskID and TaskName
- In the vss-extension.json include the files for both versions
- In the vss-extension.json include a single contribution for the task and reference only the parent folder (`Task`).

So like this:

```
 "contributions": [ 
     { 
         "id": "Task", 
         "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task", 
         "targets": [ "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks" ], 
         "properties": { "name": "Task" } // reference task root folder here.
     },
 ]
```

See also

- https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-relnote-ci-cd-tools-for-vsts-extensions-1-1-75/
- Demo project I use for testing: https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-ping-task-demo

Comment: I'd tried this as well; When uploading the extension I get the error _The task.json file was not found in contribution Task._  This happens whether I set a single entry in the files node pointing to 'Task' parent, or an entry for each task version.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of tfx?

Comment: I am. I should have mentioned before, we're on the latest TFS release, 2017.1 (not VSTS)

Comment: Don't mean tfs, I mean the tfx commandline you're using to package and publish the extension. Plus, I personally haven't tried multi-version task extensions on tfs yet, only on vsts.

Comment: Yes, tfx v0.4.5, and TFS 2017.1. Sorry for the confusion. I just wanted to be clear that we're not using VSTS, in case you were aware of some limitations in TFS.

Comment: This only became possible recently... I'm checking if it works against 2017.1, you could try publishing it privately to the VSTS marketplace to see if that works ;).

Comment: I just uploaded my multi-version extension to VSTS without any error...I suspect we're just missing the functionality in TFS 2017.1

Comment: @DanWolfe how did it work for you. I am on VSTS and I did as explained in the documentation or in the post. in the contributions part it does not seem to look for subfolders in order to check for multiple version.

Comment: @jessehouwing If you are using the 'Package Extension' in your publish pipeline confirm that the 'Override tasks version' is not checked. The tasks.json must have different major versions. You can update the .vsix to a .zip extension and browse the content of the extension after it has been packaged to ensure the content of the task.json files are correct.

Comment: @michaeldejulia, you should use the override task version! Just set it to not update the major version and you'll be fine.

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm using azure devops, have folder Task/TaskV0 and Task/TaskV1, include in files:     "files": [
        {"path": "TaskV0"},
        {"path": "TaskV1"}
    ],
and in contribute:             "properties": {
                "name": "Task"
            } 
but when upload to marketplace I get error 'The task.json file was not found in contribution Task'
please help :)

Comment: You should have `{ "files": [ { "path": "Task" } ] }` a single path entry for your whole task folder. Or possibly `{ "files": [ { "path": "Task/TaskV0" }, { "path": "Task/TaskV1" } ] }`