# How do I create different versions in TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Suppose I have 4 tasks created on a development server in the TFS. After exporting to the production server I just want to split i.e. make the release for the specific set of tasks e.g. for task 1 and 2 I want to create separate release and for task 3 and 4 I want to create another release i.e. different versions.

How would that be possible?

I want to create different releases/versions for different users?

I am using TFS 2015. I am talking about source control.

Comment: You're going to need to describe what you are talking about better. Are you talking about source control? Read up on branching strategies.

Comment: yeah source control.

Comment: You should create multi different workspaces for users. This link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789135/tfs-custom-build-tasks-multiple-versions

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

For simple cases, consider using two separate shelve-sets. Include them on the branch one after the other, with a release of the first performed before the second is included. For more complex cases, use separate branches.

---

**Longer answer:**

You can use different branches for this if you want, but a simpler option (at least for smaller tasks) may be to just *shelve* your changes. That simply means that you store your changes on the server, and revert your branch to it's original state.

You should be able to do this by right-clicking on on the project, and selecting *shelve*. To re-include the shelved changes, look for "Pending Changes" under the Team Explorer. Under "Actions", you see "Find Shelvesets", which you can use to "Unshelve" your sets.

For your case then, you might want to try to create two shelve-sets: One for your first two tasks, and one for your last two tasks. You should then be able to create a release that includes the first set of changes. When you're done with that, you can unshelve your second set, and create a release for that separately.

Note however, that this will mean handling two releases in the same branch. If the change sets are complex, or you expect any major issues with either change, it may be better to use separate branches instead; that will preserve the history related to each change in each respective branch (this might also make rollback necessary, if it becomes necessary?).

In short: Separate branches means a little more work when merging them back together later, but makes it easier to work on each set of changes separately.